# Problem with SplitViewController: Root in second plane when I show popover

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have the next problem with the split view controller: I have one view controller that add other view with an animation from the left (under the root view). All works fine but when I press the button and show the popover in portrait orientation and then come back to landscapen orientation the view appear above the root controller.

I try to bring the rootview to up but it doesn't work. Someone could help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I can solve the problem with:

```
[[[delegate splitViewController] view] bringSubviewToFront:[[[[delegate splitViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] view]];
```